# How to delete an image using default_storage.delete(file_name) in Django View?

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

So I have been creating a **Fingerprint Matching system using Django Rest Framework**. Whenever I send a fingerprint from frontend to backend to match with the stored fingerprints. The fingerprint is getting stored there which is not what I want. I want to delete it once it's use is over.

Here is the Error Image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/MCXcv.png

```
def post(self, request, format = None):
    serializer = serializers.MatchSerializer(data = request.data)

    if serializer.is_valid():

        #Fetching the stored fingerprints in a different serializer.
        queryset = models.Profile.objects.all()
        serializer2 = serializers.ProfileSerializer(queryset, many=True)
        data = serializer2.data

        #Initialized a result list which will be appended with the name of the user whose 
        #fingerprint is matched.
    
        result = []
       
        file = request.FILES['fingerprint']
        file_name = default_storage.save(file.name, file)

        file = default_storage.open(file_name) 
        file_url = default_storage.url(file_name)
        fImage = cv2.imread(str(file))

        for i in range(len(data)):
            print(data[i].get('fingerprint'))
            DbImage = cv2.imread('C:/Users/ShalomAlexander/Documents/4th Year 
                       Project/Django/FingerprintMatch/' + data[i].get('fingerprint'))

            if(isMatch(fImage, DbImage)): 
                result.append(data[i].get('name'))
        
        #This is not working as expected because its raising an error ie. " Process is still 
        #in use"    
        default_storage.delete(file_name)

        return Response(result)
```

If you have any better approach to match fingerprints or images that will also be appreciated. Thanks in advance. The current code works fine and matches the fingerprint as expected but its storing the incoming fingerprint image and I don't want that.

Comment: [mre] is required, specifically a proper traceback.

Answer (score 0):

For me this problem was solved using file_path instead of file_name:

```
file_name = default_storage.save(file.name, file)
file_path = os.path.join(settings.MEDIA_ROOT, file_name)

 . . .

default_storage.delete(file_path)
```

Comment: due to `file = default_storage.open(file_name)`, the file should still be open. you're running that on linux, aren't you? the error only happens on windows because windows file systems work differently.

Answer (score 0):

```
file = default_storage.open(file_name)
...
default_storage.delete(file_name)
```

**That is** why that file is open when you try to delete it.

This has nothing to do with OpenCV. The point of a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) is to make you figure out where the issue is.

Answer (score -1):

It looks like more an `opencv` issue than `django-rest-framework`'s one.
Please refer to this issue:
https://github.com/opencv/opencv/issues/12342

Looks like your solution might be just to upgrade your `opencv` package version.

Comment: Well it worked out without upgrading it. Thanks.

Comment: **not** an opencv error. a [mre] would have shown that. the file is still open because `file = default_storage.open(file_name)`